# How can I replace a domain name in HTML when I don't know the subdomain?

Tags: regex, perl

I have HTML code in a scalar. The HTML code can contain URLs of a certain domain that I want to replace. For instance:

```
my $code = <<ENDCODE;
  <img src="http://server1.olddomain.com/image1.jpg">
  <img src="http://server5.otherdomain.com/image2.jpg">
  <img src="http://server2.olddomain.com/image3.jpg">
ENDCODE
```

The server part of the URL can be anything (so isn't necessarily "www"). I wish to replace all image URLs that point to olddomain.com, to newdomain.com but only if the image exists on newdomain.com. So I can't simply do a straight replace, but need to call a function (that does the necessary checking) instead. So I thought I'd do something like this:

```
$code =~ s/src=\"(.+?\.olddomain\.com\/.+?)\"/URLReplace($1)/gsie;
```

And URLReplace is a function that does all the checks and replaces the URL if necessary. The problem is that the regex finds two matches:

```
http://www.olddomain.com/image1.jpg
```

and

```
http://www.otherdomain.com/image2.jpg">\n<img src="http://www.olddomain.com/image3.jpg
```

The problem is of course that the first `.+?` captures everything up until the next ".olddomain.com" which, in the second match, is `http://www.somedomain.com/image2.jpg">\n<img src="http://www`.

So how can I solve this?

Comment: Do you mean `<<` instead of `>>`?

Comment: Yes sorry, that was a typo. I'll correct it - in reply to both your comments. :)

Comment: Most likely the correct approach is using a HTML parser to process (and optionally replace) the `img` URLs.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of regexes, you can use change the HTML with a DOM. Mojo::DOM supports CSS selectors to match on substrings in an attribute. Once you've found the nodes you want to change, you can use the features of Mojo::URL (or any URI lib) to replace the host name:

```
use v5.10;
use Mojo::DOM;
use Mojo::URL;

my $code = <<~'ENDCODE';
  <img src="http://server1.olddomain.com/image1.jpg">
  <img src="http://server5.otherdomain.com/image2.jpg">
  <img src="http://server2.olddomain.com/image3.jpg">
ENDCODE

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($code);

my $old = ".olddomain.com";
$dom->find( "img[src*=$old]" )
    ->each( sub {
        my $url = Mojo::URL->new($_->attr('src'));
        return unless $url->host =~ m/\Q$old\E\z/;
        $url->host(  $url->host =~ s/\Q$old\E\z/\.newdomain.com/r );
        $_->attr( src => $url );
        } )
    ;

say $dom;
```

The output shows the selective update of the domains:

```
<img src="http://server1.newdomain.com/image1.jpg">
<img src="http://server5.otherdomain.com/image2.jpg">
<img src="http://server2.newdomain.com/image3.jpg">
```

The trick is that each stage limits the effect so you don't run into text that you didn't mean to change. You know you have `img` tags with a `src` that have the substring you want, then you know you are only dealing with the `src` value, then you know you are only dealing with the `host` portion of the URL.

I have extensive examples of DOM parsing and modification in [Mojolicious Web UserAgents](https://leanpub.com/mojo_web_clients).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want `.` to match a newline, don't use `/s`.

Using `.` is usually too general. If you know the URL is surrounded by double quotes, you can replace it by `[^"]`:

```
s/src="([^"]+\.olddomain\.com\/[^"]+)"/.../
```

Comment: I understand what your saying, but in fact most of the times these `<img>...</img>` are on the same line. The only reason I had put them on separate lines in my example is for readability.

Comment: @Zippy1970: Updated. Next time, try to be more realistic in your sample data, or mention the changes you made.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, one solution I found:

Insead of using

```
s/src=\"(.+?\.olddomain\.com\/.+?)\"/URLReplace($1)/gsie;
```

I should use

```
s/src=\"([^\.]+?\.olddomain\.com\/.+?)\"/URLReplace($1)/gsie;
```

The difference being that instead of using `.` (which matches any character), I now use `[^\.]` which matches any character *but* the dot. So it stops matching at the first dot it encounters.

Comment: Note that inside a character class, the normal metacharacters aren't meta any and you don't need to escape them. The `^` is special at the start and the `-` is special when it is between two other characters.